# Why does socket closing on C# side kill main thread on C++ side?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, sockets

I have a server side on my *raspberry pi* written on C++. I have all sockets logic in another thread, so it should not affect to my *main* thread. Here is the *Servers.hpp*:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

#define S_OUT_PORT 63253

class TestServer
{
public:
    static void Start();
private:
    static bool threadIsRunning;
    static void LoopOut();
};
```

Here is the *.cpp* file:

```cpp
#include <Servers.hpp>

bool TestServer::threadIsRunning = true;

void TestServer::Start()
{
    threadIsRunning = true;
    thread th(LoopOut);
    th.detach();
}

void TestServer::LoopOut()
{

        try
        {
            int server_fd, new_socket;
            struct sockaddr_in address;
            int opt = 1;
            int addrlen = sizeof(address);

            if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
            {
                // logging
                return;
            }

            if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
            {
                // logging
                return;
            }
            address.sin_family = AF_INET;
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
            address.sin_port = htons(S_OUT_PORT);

            if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0)
            {
                // logging
                return;
            }

            if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
            {
                // logging
                return;
            }

            if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0)
            {
                // logging
                return;
            }

            cout << "SC got connection" << endl;

            while (true)
            {
                 //SendString(new_socket, "null:null", 9);
                int strLen = 9;
                string str = "null:null";

                char b[4] = { (strLen & 0xff), ((strLen >> 8) & 0xff), ((strLen >> 16) & 0xff), ((strLen >> 24) & 0xff) };
                const char* p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(b);
                send(new_socket, p, 4, 0);
                send(new_socket, str.c_str(), strLen, 0);

                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(20));
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            cout << "SC error" << endl;
        }
    cout << "SC thread exited" << endl;
}
```

And I start this server just calling `TestServer::Start()` in main:

```cpp
int main()
{
    try
    {
        TestServer::Start();

        while (true)
        {
            cout << "Test" << endl;
        
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(3000));
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Main error" << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then when I'm trying to connect to the server from my pc using C# everything is ok. But when I close the socket from C# side, C++ just terminates. Here is how I shut down connection on C# side:

```cs
sct.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sct.Close();
```

What could be the reason of this? Why does socket's *shutdown* and *close* kill my main thread in C++?
**EDIT 1:** Here is the output on the server side:

```
Test
Test
Test
SC got connection
Test
pi@raspberrypi:~/picadCpp/build $
```

And the loop in `LoopOut` method removed, but result is the same...

Comment: Not a solution, but having `using namespace std;` in a header may give issues down the line.

Comment: @DS_London thanks, didn't know about that!

Comment: What’s the output on the server side?

Comment: Most likely the server side crashes. The code in `LoopOut()` needs to be changed considerably. You should only call `socket()`, `bind()` and `listen()` once. The should be moved outside the loop. And there needs to be some way of detecting that the client has closed the connection.

Comment: @Codo I have this loop only to be able to reconnect to the server. I removed it, but the result is the same. Question is updated.

Comment: The typical server calls `socket()`, `bind()` and `listen()` once and then many connections from clients using `accept()`. Often `accept()` creates a new thread so multiple clients can be handled concurrently. The code handling the communication with the client ends the thread if the client disconnect. Your current code can accept a single client and has no way of gracefully ending if the client disconnects. It cannot handle multiple clients, neither concurrently nor serially.

Comment: @Codo Thanks for the comment! But I don't need for multiple connections to one server. I just want to reconnect to it, after dissconnetion. But that's not the point. Even if it can't handle multiple connection, why does it stop my main thread? Or what should I do, so my program can gracefully end if client disconnects?

Comment: And it seems you aren’t catching any exceptions anyway? Maybe try adding `catch(…)` clauses, as ,AFAIK, the std::exception class is only for exceptions thrown by the std library: ie not the socket library.

Comment: @DS_London thanks for the comment. But where could I find all possible exception that could be thrown by socket library? I searched some sites but can't find anything about it. And I tried to write AFAIK instead of std::exception, but cmake gave me errors, that it doesn't know what is AFAIK (Maybe I do something wrong, I don't understand it). But anyway. If it doesn't catch with std::exception, then it should write the error message to bash. isn't it?

Comment: AFAIK =“ as far as I know”. Instead of `catch (const std::exception& e)` use `catch(…)`. The ellipsis (…) means “catch anything that hasn’t already been caught”. That said I dont know how Pi manifests exceptions.

Comment: @DS_London Oh, really, it was quite funny :) But anyway it didn't help

Comment: Some hints: Aside from the SIGPIPE signal, `send()` will return 0 or a negative number if the connection closes. No signal is triggered, if the client uses a half close. The socket library you are using is a C library. C does not have exceptions. So no exceptions are thrown. To reconnect, just call `accept()` again. As it is currently, the server socket is still open after the client disconnect. Opening it a second time will fail.

Comment: ok, thanks to all of You. I'll try it all